# Rancher TLS Certificate Authority

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Quick question, in Rancher is it possible to use lets-encrypt to sign the k8s TLS certs (etcd, kub-api, etc).  I have a compliance requirement to sign my k8s environment with a valid trusted CA chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is actually one of the [recommended options](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/helm-rancher/#4-choose-your-ssl-configuration) for the source of the certificate used for TLS termination at the Rancher server:

> Let’s Encrypt: The Let’s Encrypt option also uses cert-manager.
>   However, in this case, cert-manager is combined with a special Issuer
>   for Let’s Encrypt that performs all actions (including request and
>   validation) necessary for getting a Let’s Encrypt issued cert.

In the links below you will find a walkthrough showing how to:

- [Install cert-manager](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/helm-rancher/#5-install-cert-manager)
- [Install Rancher with Helm and Your Chosen Certificate Option](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/helm-rancher/#6-install-rancher-with-helm-and-your-chosen-certificate-option)

> This option uses cert-manager to automatically request and renew Let’s
>   Encrypt certificates. This is a free service that provides you with a
>   valid certificate as Let’s Encrypt is a trusted CA.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I have had trouble getting helm to install but that has been worked out.  I plan to attempt the cert-install shortly and will let you know.

Comment: Ok, looks like I was able to install and setup cert-manager so your guide worked great.  However it looks like it setup a rancher pod in the env (not sure what benefit that gives us?).  I was hoping this will allow LetsEncrypt to create and sign certs the the k8s services such as etcd api and controlplane ports.  Is this currently possible?

Thanks again

Comment: If this helps, my implementation of Rancher server/k8s is running in docker containers.

Comment: @grimm-muncha I think it would be better to provide more details and ask that in a separate question.